# Create relative path and being OS independent

Tags: python, linux, windows, path, operating-system

How can I get my script's file name as a relative path to `cwd` and it being OS independent?

e.g if I'm in linux it should return "./script.py" and if I'm in windows it should return ".\\script.py"

I tried with `os.path.join` and `os.path.basename(__file__)` but it returns absolute path.

Comment: Fun fact: Windows is fine with forward slashes for a while now.

Comment: @KlausD. Windows is fine with forward slashes, sure. But when I do a `os.walk` it returns the filenames with backslashes... So if I want to compare two file paths as strings, I have to create my string with backslashes too.

Comment: @KlausD., funner fact: many Windows API functions do not support slash as the path separator at all, such as the pathcch functions added in Windows 8. For example, `PathCchCombineEx` joins `"C:/spam"` and `"/eggs"` incorrectly as `"C:/spam\\/eggs"` since it does not handle "/" as a path separator.  For `"C:\\spam"` and `"\\eggs"`, however, it correctly returns `"C:\\eggs"`. There are many other such examples. Only the base file API reliably supports slash as a path separator -- and only in *normalized* paths, not in non-normalized "\\?\" prefixed paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import platform

path = os.path.basename(__file__)
run_on=platform.system()
if run_on=='Windows': path=f'.\\{path}'
elif run_on=='Linux': path=f'./{path}'

print(f'path is {path}')
```

Comment: `script_name = ".\\" + os.path.basename(__file__) if platform.system() == 'Windows' else "./" + os.path.basename(__file__)`

Did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply let `os` handle that for you?

```
path = os.path.normcase(os.path.join('.', os.path.relpath(__file__)))
```

Comment: That returns the path in lowercase. For windows it wouldn't matter. But for my string comparison it matters. How to avoid the lowercase-ing?

Comment: Removing the `normcase` will not change the case, but that is all the point of using it for path comparison. For example, `os.path.normcase('./foo\\BAR/baz.BLAH') == os.path.normcase('.\\foo\\bar\\baz.blah')` is `True` because `normcase` fixed the slashes and made the case consistent for us.

Comment: Yes, that's not why I'm not eager to use your solution even though it's valid. The reason that I'd have to use it on every path returned by `walk` is what puts me off. With @n1tr0xs solution I only have to do it once to get the correct relative path to the script. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Then you just need `os.path.join('.', os.path.relpath(__file__))` if you compare with walked files, as their slashes should already be fixed.